# javascript jquery ajax handle response with jsp format by using xml post method

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, jsp

I would like to ask whether can get specific value inside the response data in JSP format by ajax.

Below is my source code:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "xml",
        data: postParameter(),
        complete:function(data){
             if (data.readyState == 4 && data.status == 200) {
                 var response  = data.responseText;
             }
        },
    });
```

Please refer below for the response data from server

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><MYTesting_AppResponse xmlns="WebServices">
<return>
<status>success</status>
<resourceMessageBean>
<rsa_note3>To proceed, please enter your password and click "Login"</rsa_note3>
<phrase>???en.common.password.login.p3???</phrase>
<username>Username</username>
<password>Password</password>
</resourceMessageBean>
<loginFormBean>
<username>tester1</username>
</loginFormBean>
</return>
</MYTesting_AppResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

May i know how to use js to get "resourceMessageBean" from the response?

**Another response from server:**

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
<M2UPayLogin_AppResponse xmlns="WebServices">
    <return>
        <status>success</status>
        <resourceMessageBean>
            <rsa_note3>To proceed, please enter your password and click "Login"</rsa_note3>
            <phrase>Phrase</phrase>
            <username>Username</username>
            <password>Password</password>
        </resourceMessageBean>
        <loginFormBean>
            <username>tester1</username>
        </loginFormBean>
        <navigationsBean>
            <login>
            <a href="www.google.com">Login</a>
            </login>
        </navigationsBean>
    </return>
</M2UPayLogin_AppResponse>
```

How to get the "www.google.com" from navigationsBean, because i use the method below only showing the text "Login" only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        url: rootURL,
        dataType: "xml",
        data: postParameter(),
        complete:function(xml){
           $(xml).find('resourceMessageBean').each(function(){
             var username = $(this).find('username').text();
          });
        }
    });
```

**Update:**

```
   $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            url: rootURL,
            dataType: "xml",
            data: postParameter(),
            complete:function(xml){
               $(xml).find('navigationsBean').each(function(){
                 var username = $(this).find('login a').text();
              });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I would like to ask something again about this response, if the response including <a href="www.google.com">Google</a>, how can i get the "www.google.com" from tag a?

Comment: @user3479640, Can you please post the response sample here?

Comment: i aleady edit with add a new response, can teach me how to get the value inside the a tag form.

Comment: @user3479640, I have updated my answer. Please check.